# SQL mutually exclusive conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql

EDIT:

I have a table 'TableA' with columns `product, feature1, feature2`
I have another table 'TableB' with columns `'saleorder, feature1, feature2'`

Currently I use an inner join to show products with matching column values

```
SELECT distinct a.product 
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.feature1 = b.feature1 
    AND a.feature2 = b.feature2
```

Currently this shows me products from TableA that had an exact match for feature1,feature2 from TableB.

I want to modify this so that, I see those products from TableA which did not match for feature1,feature2. In a way the opposite output of the original script, showing only those products for which no saleorder with feature1 and feature2 exists.

How can I do this using T-SQL?

Comment: `WHERE A.feature3 = B.feature3 AND A.feature1 = B.feature1 AND A.feature2 = B.feature2`? Though i really suggest you fix your design and normalise it; you should have 1 `feature` column not 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` if you don't need columns from TableB

```
SELECT DISTINCT product 
FROM TableA p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB s
    WHERE s.feature1 = p.feature1 
      AND s.feature2 = p.feature2 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**: Get all the rows from the TableA with feature1 and feature 2 from TableB having NULL for rows that does not have corresponding matching values for 'feature1' and 'feature2' from TableA.

```
SELECT A.product,
       A.feature1 Afeature1,
       A.feature2 Afeature2,
       B.feature1 Bfeature1,
       B.feature2 Bfeature2
FROM   tablea A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb B
                    ON A.feature1 = B.feature1
                       AND A.feature2 = B.feature2;
```

--- this is will have output like this

```
product  Afeature1   Afeature2    Bfeature1     Bfeature2 
abcd     l           l             m             m         
efgh     x           y             NULL          NULL    -----> this is what you want.
```

**Step 2**: So now you just have to filter out the NOT NULL's for Columns from TableB that is obtained in the earlier output.

```
SELECT productA,Afeature1,Afeature2
FROM   (SELECT A.product productA,
               A.feature1 Afeature1,
               A.feature2 Afeature2,
               B.feature1 Bfeature1,
               B.feature2 Bfeature2
        FROM   tablea A
               LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb B
                            ON A.feature1 = B.feature1
                               AND A.feature2 = B.feature2)
WHERE  bfeature1 IS  NULL
       AND bfeature2 IS NULL;
```

Final output:

```
product  Afeature1   Afeature2     
efgh     x           y
```

Answer (score 1):

`from TableA which did not match for feature1 and feature2, but matched for feature3`:

```
SELECT distinct a.feature3, a.feature1, a.feature2, b.feature1, b.feature2
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.feature3 = b.feature3  
    AND a.feature1 <> b.feature1
    AND a.feature2 <> b.feature2
```

Comment: Apologies, I did not explain the question properly. I have edited it to make it easier to explain.